# Kubuntu login screen issue

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, password

i am sorry if i in wrong place to ask,and to share my problem and what i found,but i hope you give me the answers what i look.

Well the situation - have installed Kubuntu to my client,and he was happy as elephant till,once he tried to log into system and system said him about wrong password.He tried to enter few times but nothing happens,then he tried to switch user(only one user registered in system!)and then the password works.But system unable to load,only KDE loading screen,then black screen and system halted.I found the what a problem is.First my client enter password on another language instead English - he entered password at Hebrew.Second problem is a strange system behavior.You can do same thing to check this - on log screen click on "switch user",type wrong password and,system halted.

First thing i want to warn people who face same problem.The "fix" of this issue just enter the password correct :D And don't press switch user if you have only one user on system.

Second - i want to help by reporting this bug,but where i have to report?KDE team?Kubuntu?Ubuntu?To everyone? :D

Thank you for you patience and you answers.

P.S.System Kubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.Machines:Dell Inspiron 3000 8gb ram,Virtual Box VM 8gb virtual ram on Amd FX8350 32gb

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org is what I use.

Comment: you should clean up your questions to contain only one issue. its quite hard to read. the part about different languages and switching users seems like different problems.

Answer (score 0):

About language for typing passwords, I do have keyboard switcher setup for `sddm`, that is configurable in the login settings.

switching user, although it is skin similary, is done by a different program `kscreenlocker` I would report the bug to their developers via https://bugs.kde.org website.

hope this helps

Comment: I don't ask about switching languages,i only was telling what actions did my client.The bug is only  in switching users.Thank you for you answers.